# ValueError: shapes (100,784) and (4,6836) not aligned: 784 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, valueerror

Update: I fixed the error, so I only need an answer on the second question!

I'm fairly new in Python and got an error while performing a task. I looked for this error, but didn't find my answer on it.

So, this is what I am trying to do.

I want to build a neural network that is able to predict a value. 
The code I used for the class is as follows

```
# neural network class definition
```

class neuralNetwork:

```
#Step 1: initialise the neural network: number of input layers, hidden layers and output layers
def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):
    #set number of nodes in each input, hidden, output layer
    self.inodes = inputnodes
    self.hnodes = hiddennodes
    self.onodes = outputnodes

    #link weight matrices, wih and who (weights in hidden en output layers), we are going to create matrices for the multiplication of it to get an output
    #weights inside the arrays (matrices) are w_i_j, where link is from node i to node j in the next layer
    #w11 w21
    #w12 w22 etc
    self.wih = numpy.random.normal(0.0,pow(self.inodes,-0.5),( self.hnodes, self.inodes))
    self.who = numpy.random.normal(0.0,pow(self.hnodes,-0.5),( self.onodes, self.hnodes))

    # setting the learning rate
    self.lr = learningrate

    # activation function is the sigmoid function
    self.activation_function = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)

    pass

#Step 2: training the neural network - adjust the weights based on the error of the network
def train(self, inputs_list, targets_list):
    #convert input lists to 2d array (matrice)
    inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
    targets = numpy.array(targets_list, ndmin=2).T

    #calculate signals into hidden layer
    hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)
    #calculate signals emerging from hidden layer
    hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

    #calculate signals into final output layer
    final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
    #calculate signals emerging from final output layer
    final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)
    # output layer error is the (target-actual)
    output_errors = targets -final_outputs
    #hidden layer error is the output_errors, split by weights, recombined at hidden nodes
    hidden_errors = numpy.dot(self.who.T, output_errors)

    #update the weights for the links between the hidden and output layers
    self.who += self.lr * numpy.dot((output_errors*final_outputs * (1.0-final_outputs)),numpy.transpose(hidden_outputs))

    # update the weights for the links between the input and hidden layers
    self.wih += self.lr*numpy.dot((hidden_errors*hidden_outputs*(1.0-hidden_outputs)),numpy.transpose(inputs))

    pass

#Seap 3: giving an output- thus making the neural network perform a guess
def query(self, inputs_list):
    #convert input lists to 2d array (matrice)
    inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T

    #calculate signals into hidden layer
    hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)
    #calculate signals emerging from hidden layer
    hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

    #calculate signals into final output layer
    final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
    #calculate signals emerging from final output layer
    final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)

    return final_outputs
```

I obviously imported the necessary things first:

```
import numpy 
#scipy.special for the sigmoid function expit()
import scipy.special
```

I then created an instance of the neural network:

```
#number of input, hidden and output nodes
input_nodes = 784
hidden_nodes = 100
output_nodes = 10

#learning rate is 0.8
learning_rate = 0.8

#create instance of neural network
n = neuralNetwork(input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes, learning_rate)
```

After this, I read the excel file with the inputs and the target

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("Desktop\\PythonTest.xlsx")
```

The file looks like this:

[snapshot of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULAct.png)

The columns h, P, D, o are inputs and the column EOQ is the number that the neural network should learn.

So, I first did this:

```
xcol=["h","P","D","o"]
ycol=["EOQ"]
x=df[xcol].values
y=df[ycol].values
```

To define the x and y columns. x are the inputs and y is the target.

I now want to train the neural network on this data and I used these lines of code;

```
# train the neural network
# go through all records in the training data set 
for record in df:
inputs = x
targets = y
n.train(inputs, targets)
pass
```

This gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
  last)
  <ipython-input-23-48e0e741e8ec> in <module>()
  4     inputs = x
  5     targets = y
   ----> 6     n.train(inputs, targets)
  7     pass

  <ipython-input-13-12c121f6896b> in train(self, inputs_list, targets_list)
 31 
 32         #calculate signals into hidden layer
  ---> 33         hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)
 34         #calculate signals emerging from hidden layer
 35         hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

 ValueError: shapes (100,784) and (4,6836) not aligned: 784 (dim 1) != 4 
 (dim 0)
```

So two questions:

1. What is going wrong in the code?
2. I want to add an extra column in the file with the guess of the neural network after it is trained. How do I achieve this?

Many thanks in advance and appreciate any feedback!

Cheers

Steven

Comment: The parameters of `hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)` don't have the correct shapes for a matrix multiplication.

In order to multiply to matrices `a * b` the second dimension of `a` must match the first dimension of `b`. 

This is not happening, `self.wih` has shape `(100,784)` while `inputs` has shape `(4,6836)`, so you got the error (`784 != 4`). 

 `assert self.wih.shape[1] == inputs.shape[0]`

Comment: thanks! But where do I have to insert "assert self.wih.shape[1] == inputs.shape[0]" in my code??

Comment: The assert is only a sanity check before calling `np.dot`. I don't know where is the problem that lead to that error, I'm just telling you what the error actually is saying!

Comment: aha! Thanks! I found the mistake. I'm stating that there were 784 inputs and 10 outputs, but this is not true. The only question now: How can I add a column to the file with the guess of the network?

Answer (score 0):

You are already using pandas, so you can simply get all the output, and make a new column to pandas `df`.

```
result = [nn.query(input) for input in df]
df['result'] = result
```